# .attr('data-content') works on one page but not on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to fix this for quite some time and now I'm literally running out of options. I am using jQuery,MVC and have an ajax call which basically retrieves me some data which I want to display in a Bootstrap `popover`.

Now this part of code is working perfectly in one View, but in another page, this code refuses to do anything. Now I do not know whether the error lies within jQuery, or the bootstrap.

I have a popover, which I want to change its `data-content` dynamically. When I debugged it, the Data IS being retrieved, so the problem lies somewhere within the jQuery.

```
     $(".test").mouseover(function () {
     cell = $(this).attr("data-val");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Input/GetExpenditureEntityCell',
        data: { CellID: cell },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;



            alert(data.xID + "x" + data.yID + "\n" + data.value)
            $("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID).addClass("hasComment");
            $("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID).attr('data-content', data.value);

        }
    });
});
```

This is where I'm calling it.

```
 <a href="#" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-val="2503x2510" data-target="#expModal" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg value test" id="2#2">
```

1) Basically I have like spreadsheet cells where each of them have an ID, on hover I want to retrieve the data of that particular cell. I tried multiple ways, `destroy`, and so on.

2) I tried at first setting some static text in `data-content`, but whenever I tried to change it, it never changed (for example stayed 'hello'). in the Console, there are NO errors.

Any help please?

**EDIT**. This is a screenshot of the data which is being brought by the DB
[image: Debugger]
[image: Alert]

Comment: Sorry, I'm editing it now.

Comment: `.attr('content', data.value);` You are setting here `content` attribute, not `data-content`. Is it your expected behaviour?

Comment: That is a typo from my side whilst copying. EVen when I used `data-content`, it has no effect. Funnily, on Another page, THIS EXACT coding, Worked and the data-content switched just fine

Comment: So check than `$("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID)` matches relevant element, e.g: `console.log($("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID))`

Comment: It does, the data is being retrieved, I'll show also a screenshot of the debugger just in case.

Comment: And are you using duplicate IDs? You have to try replicating your issue somewhere it can be checked. And still not sure how do you check than data attribute isn't updated. Inspecting element in browser or what? And does the class `hasComment` being added?

Comment: No Duplicates IDs, the IDs are being generated like a graph, (2503x2601), (2503x2602) and so on. so no way there are duplicates otherwise the system will crash

Comment: But why showing what works but not what doesn't work??? What are you expecting to update data attribute to do? What is element you are targeting? And again, how do you check it doesn't work? MCVE...

Comment: This Excerpt of Code in this Page is NOT working. I want the `data-content` to update (its popover) with the Data seen in the `alert`.

Comment: Sorry but if you don't answer any question previously asked, it is really hard to help... And you stilld didn't probide the HTML markup for element you are trying to match regarding `#2503x2510` selector

Comment: I am using this line to try and change the content `$("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID).attr('data-content', data.value);`.for some reason, it worked on one, this one not. I'll try another Selector if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element has `id="2#2"`, but your selector code is `$("#" + data.xID + "x" + data.yID)`. I don't know what those values are, but regardless that's not going to produce `2#2`. Somewhere you want an `x` instead of a `#` or vice-versa.

---

I should also note that CSS ID selectors are not allowed to start with a literal digit. That is, the selectors `#2x2` and `#2#2` are both invalid. jQuery accepts them if you use them *on their own* in `$()`, because it converts those into `document.getElementById` calls, but they're invalid and won't work if you combine them with anything (`$("#2x2 span")` will fail, for instance).

If you're going to use CSS ID selectors, best to start them with a non-digit. If you can't, then using attribute selector syntax makes it valid without getting into complicated escaping: `$('[id="#2x2"]')`.

Comment: I am using `data-val` in this case to get the ID which is 2503x2510. `cell = $(this).attr("data-val");`

Comment: @DodoSombrero: Then why is the question asking about `data-content`? I don't see anything relating to `cell` there. If you haven't shown the element you're trying to set `data-content` on, **why not**?

Comment: Because for some reason, the `data-content` is not updating my data with the data I am retrieving from the DB

Comment: @DodoSombrero: You need to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), the question is unclear and missing at least some information (the element you're setting `data-content` on).

Comment: I updated some code, what I can't understand is, how in one Page this exact coding WORKED, but on this webpage it is not working when both pages are using the same structure. Could it be something jQuery side?

Comment: @DodoSombrero It is more surely something on your side. Maybe element doesn't exists at time you are trying to update its attribute or your observation is wrong or...???

Comment: I noticed the mistake I was doing, Thank you T.J. Crowder, was a silly mistake. When I compared the code to the Page which was working, I noticed that the ID I was using was infact the 2503x2510. In this page though it was the "'2#2" which is the ID of the cell. Something I didn't notice. Thank you.